# Display specific student record from Mysql database using AngularJS $http

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, http

I have this table in mysql database

[image]

When a student enter his rollno in input field it should display his record.
[image]

---

Its my code

```
<div class="col-sm-3">

<input type="text" ng-model="filterTask" class="form-control search header-elements-margin" placeholder="Enter your rollno">

</div>
</div></div>
<div class="widget-body ">

<div class="task">
 <div ng-class="{strike:task.STATUS==2}" style="font-weight:bold;"><span>ID </span> <span> Name </span> <span> Class </span> <span> Father </span> <span> Teacher</span></div>
    <label class="checkbox" ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter : filterTask">

    <div ng-class="{strike:task.STATUS==2}"><span>{{task.id}} </span> <span> {{task.name}} </span> <span> {{task.class}} </span> <span> {{task.father}} </span> <span> {{task.teacher}}</span></div>

    </label>
</div>

<script>
    //Define an angular module for our app
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('studentController', function($scope, $http) {
  getTask(); // Load all available tasks 
  function getTask(){  
  $http.post("getStudents.php").success(function(data){
        $scope.tasks = data;
       });
  };
});
    </script>
```

It is displaying all records, but I need to show a specific result when a rollno entered. It is like a filter, but I want to get specific student result when enter his rollno.

Comment: What have you tried so far? `getStudents.php?studentId=100` is a starting point.